# If statement in table in django-templates

Tags: python, django, django-templates

**say we have table in template**

```
<table class="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
            
             <th>Status</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
              {% for student in students %}
            <tr>
             
             {% if {{student.academic_status}}=="promoted" %}
             <td class=text-success>promoted</td>
             {% endif %}
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

So is it possible using if statement in  table in **django-templates**

Comment: Yeah course you can!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are already in a *template tag*, you should *not* use curly brackets (`{{ … }}`) for the variable, so:

```
{% if student.academic_status == "promoted" %}
    …
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

**The correct way to add if statement in Django Templates**

follow me !

**if statement**

```
{% if condition %}

   {{here you add the key that you using in the views page exactly context}}

{% endif %}
```